# stop focusing even i dont click outsite of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written small piece of code where i have a div container and in that div has `spans` and `forms` `textbox` `btns`. when i click on btn1, container height increase and show an textbox but when i click on textbox div goes focus out. How is possible that when i click on btn1 and its stay focus in even i click on textbox(after click on btn1 and show blackbox) it shouldnt goes focusout and when i click out site of container it should goes focusout ? how can i do please help me ?

```js
var tt = $.noConflict();
tt(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".qta").focus(function() {

    $(".gutt").css({
      'display': 'inline-block'
    });
    $(".gutte").addClass('grandisciti');
  });

  $(".gutte").focusout(function() {

    $(".gutt").css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    $(".gutte").removeClass('grandisciti');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #c1c2c3;
 }
 .gutte {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 550px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #000;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   margin-left: 32%;
   margin-top: 30px;
   padding-top: 2.5px;
   padding-left: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 2px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .ati {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   position: static;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 105px;
   height: 45px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   padding: 0px 10px;
   border: none;
   background-color: #ccc;
   /*border:2px solid #ccc;*/
   border-radius: 10px;
   outline: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: 0.8s all;
   font-size: 120%;
   color: #000;
 }
 .grandisciti {
   width: 600;
   height: 300px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
 .gutt {
   display: none;
   width: 530px;
      margin:10px;
   background-color: #000;
 }
 .tref {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 80%;
   height: 100px;
   resize: none;
   outline: none;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 15px;
   border: 5px solid #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

body
<div tabindex="1" class="gutte">
  <div  class="irj fjr_p05gure rddre ">
    <button class="ati qta ">btn1</button>
    <button class="ati ">btn2</button>
    <button class="ati ">bt3</button>

  </div>
  <span class="gutt">
    <input type="text" class="tref"/>
  </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a close look at the event passed to the focusout function, in particular the target attribute. Your gutte div will likely be catching a focusout event generated by the button. You will need to put in some conditions so that you don't collapse gutte when focus is moving around within gutte.

Comment: which type of conditions ? please can u make an jsfiddle